# Insert Into Database From Array Using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, insert

I have database A with field hotel,order_type and description. I want insert value to database A from array $new_array.

//array $new_array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [order_type] => 1
        [currency] => 26
        [net] => 
        [rate] => 
        [amount] => 
        [bank_surcharge] => 
        [ticket] => 
        [profit] => 
        [selling_price] => 
        [description] => a
        [hotel] => 1
        [vendor] => 11
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order_type] => 2
        [currency] => 27
        [net] => 
        [rate] => 
        [amount] => 
        [bank_surcharge] => 
        [ticket] => 
        [profit] => 
        [selling_price] => 
        [description] => b
        [hotel] => 1
        [vendor] => 11
    )
...
...
}
```

i tried this script but nothing happened :(

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($new_array['order_type']); $i++){
    mssql_query("INSERT INTO A(hotel_id, order_type,    description) 
    VALUES('$new_array[$i]', '$new_array[$i]', '$new_array[$i]')");
}
```

How to do this with php? please anyone help me.

Comment: i think you don't have to pass sizeof($new_array['order_type'] you may try count($new_array)

Comment: thanks for all nice people out there who help me out.. you're all the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) your loop is invalid, should be `sizeof($new_array)`

2) your array data access for SQL statement is invalid

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($new_array); $i++){
    mssql_query("INSERT INTO A(hotel_id, order_type, description) VALUES({$new_array[$i]['hotel']}, '{$new_array[$i]['type']}', '{$new_array[$i]['description']}')");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass `Connection` reference and loop as:

```
foreach($new_array as $each){
    mssql_query($conn, "INSERT INTO A(hotel_id, order_type, description) 
    VALUES('{$each['hotel']}', '{$each['order_type']}', '{$each['description']}')");
}
```

Comment: query using mssql but the connection created for mysql

Comment: Thanks @AllenChak, I missed db. It was MS-Sql. I though it is MySQL.

kroseva please try again. changed for MS-Sql.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
foreach($new_array as $item) {
    mssql_query("INSERT INTO A (hotel_id, order_type, description) 
    VALUES('". $item['hotel'] ."', '". $item['order_type'] ."', '". $item['description']. "')");
}
```

`foreach` is very similar to `for` loop but it simply iterates over all array elements. You don't need to care about the array size.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($new_array as $val){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO A(order_type, description) VALUES($val['order_type'], $val['description'])");
}
```

This code doesn't insert `hotel_id` because it is primary key of the table A.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($new_array['order_type']); $i++) {
    mssql_query("INSERT INTO A(hotel_id, order_type, description) VALUES ('$new_array[$i]["hotel"]', '$new_array[$i]["order_type"]', '$new_array[$i]["description"]')");
}
```

This should work I guess, haven't tested it though.

Comment: invalid variable of `$new_array['order_type']` for function `sizeof()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($new_array['order_type']); $i++){
    mssql_query("INSERT INTO A(hotel_id, order_type,    description) 
    VALUES('".$new_array[$i]['hotel']."', '".$new_array[$i]['order_type']."', '".$new_array[$i]['description']."')");
}
```

Comment: invalid variable of `$new_array['order_type']` for function `sizeof()`